# Is a copy constructor always created by default?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

As I knew until today there are four default things create when creating a new class. "Default constructor", "Destructor", "Copy constructor" and "Assignment operator". But today when I was going trough a C++ article, it said that there can be situations where the copy constructor is not create by default.

1. Is that true?
2. If it is, in which situations?
3. In those situations, how can an instance of that class be passed by value?

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) under "Deleted implicitly-declared copy constructor". In those cases, you simply cannot pass objects by value unless you specify your own copy constructor.

Answer (score 8):

1) Yes, there can be situations where the copy constructor is not created by default.

2) The conditions where the implicitly declared default constructor is *deleted* are laid out in **12.8 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]**:

**12.8.7** is about how the declaration of other special member functions affect the implicitly declared copy constructor. Whenever the class declares a copy constructor, a move constructor or a move assignment operator. If it declares any one of those, then you don't get an implicitly declared one.

> ...
>
> <sup>7</sup> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition
>   declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
>   implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise,
>   it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the
>   class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared
>   destructor.

**12.8.11** is about how the data members and base classes affect the implicitly declared copy constructor. Essentially, if the class has any data members or base classes that are not copyable, the implicitly declared copy constructor is `delete`d:

> <sup>11</sup> An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an inline public
>   member of its class. A defaulted copy/ move constructor for a class X
>   is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if X has:
>
> — a variant member with a
>   non-trivial corresponding constructor and X is a union-like class,
>
> — a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot
>   be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s
>   corresponding constructor, results in an ambiguity or a function that
>   is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,
>
> — a direct or virtual base class B that cannot be copied/moved because overload
>   resolution (13.3), as applied to B’s corresponding constructor,
>   results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible
>   from the defaulted constructor,
>
> — any direct or virtual base class or
>   non-static data member of a type with a destructor that is deleted or
>   inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,
>
> — for the copy
>   constructor, a non-static data member of rvalue reference type, or
>
> ...

3) You can declare and define (either by providing an implementation or `default`ing a copy constructor, or a move copy constructor, or both.

Comment: Uhm, there's surely something missing here... For example, there's no default copy constructor when you have members that are not copy constructible (e.g. references or other classes with deleted/not accessible copy constructor). (yes, it is *deleted* and not just "not created", but this is probably the case OP is most interested in)

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, In these cases the constructors are *implicitly deleted*. I am looking for the part of the standard where this is layed out. I will edit the question soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. For example, if a member of the class is not copyable/assignable (e.g. a member has a private assignment operator and private copy constructor), then you won't be able to rely on a default copy constructor for the containing class. If you want the containing class to be copyable/assignable under those circumstances, then you need to define those operations explicitly.

That being said, in most cases, you should avoid passing by value. In most circumstances, you should be passing an object by constant reference or passing a smart pointer (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) of your object. Passing by value (and any code that does an unnecessary amount of copying) will produce less efficient code than cases where you are able to reuse existing implementations. Additionally, for polymorphic objects, pass-by-value causes "slicing" (the functionality is truncated from the runtime type to the declared type to which the object is being copied), and so pass-by-value is particularly dangerous and error-prone when operating with any data types that might possibly be inherited.

**Edit**
To clarify the above a little bit... in terms of passing by const-reference vs passing by value, the decision should depend on the size of the object and how expensive it is to copy. Boost provides a handy mechanism in "call traits" ([call_traits<T>::param_type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm)) to automatically select between a value and a const reference based on the size of an object. When making this decision, it's also useful to distinguish between value types (objects that behave similarly to primitives -- for example, by overloading various operators and that are copyable, assignable, and cannot be inherited) and user-defined polymorphic types. Whenever you have a type that declares a virtual method, as a general rule of thumb, that object should be passed by reference or const reference to avoid the slicing which I mentioned above.

In terms of passing by smart pointer, generally this is done when transferring or sharing ownership (otherwise you should generally just pass around a reference to the object in question).

Comment: You says `then you won't be able to rely on a default copy constructor for the containing class` that means it creates the copy constructor or totally not?

Comment: For all practical purposes, if you write code that invokes the copy constructor and you don't implement one explicitly, you will get a compiler error. Now, if this is because the default implementation gets generated but relies on a private method or because it simply does not get generated is a distinction that makes no difference to me (language lawyers tend to get very pedantic about this sort of thing, though).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Hi, small world. Passing by value is just fine _for values_.

Comment: Regarding "in most cases" - what the OP finds most common will depend a lot on their problem domain, so while I don't disagree in general I'm not sure how useful that observation is without a few counter-examples.  "Value semantic types" supporting math-like `+`, `*` etc. operators typically accept the left-hand-side parameter by value, `operator=` is often written using the copy-and-swap idiom, with the first parameter copy-constructed etc..  Perhaps a guideline like "when you need both the current value and a modified version...".

Comment: Yep, funny to find you here, @StevenSudit. Even for value-like objects, if they are large-ish, passing by value rather than const reference is often a mistake. However, I see from the many downvotes that I need to clarify my response.

Comment: I've rarely found much use for having smart pointers as parameters, especially `unique_ptr`. Passing things by value on the other hand, I do quite often. It depends upon the purpose of the parameter though (for example, arguments which you need a copy of anyway), which is why the advice "in most cases, you should avoid" is not very helpful, imo.

Comment: @TonyD, the left-hand side is not "pass-by-value". The left-hand side is an "lvalue". There's no copying involved there.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: I'm not talking about `+=` from a client perspective... I'm talking about an implementation ala `T& operator+=(T lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }`, where the `lhs` parameter is passed by value.

Comment: @TonyD: Is that supposed to be `operator+=`? Or `operator+`?

Comment: @TonyD, that definition doesn't make sense. If implementing "+=", then it should be "T&", not "T".

Comment: P.S. And this is why people stop answering on StackOverflow... I should go back on Google+ where there are no downvotes.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley that one was meant to be `+=`, but I just noticed I'd missed a '&' on the return type... fixed.  Building on that, `T operator+(T lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }`.

Comment: @TonyD: In that case, you're returning a reference to a local. Oh, and your operator is infinitely recursive.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: if you care about downvotes, yeah - avoid this place - reputation and votes are a sporadic side-effect of useful contribution.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: you're right - not a good day - should be a member function `T& ::operator(const T& rhs) { ...; return *this; }`.  Point stands for `operator+` implementation though....

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Right, for a function parameter, we want to avoid unnecessary copying, but that's a separate issue from whether the object is a value. A good example is std::string, which is best passed by reference because it can get big, but still supports copying.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Oh, and when your magic number is well over 10k, I recommend taking honest downvotes in stride. It's only the strategic downvotes that piss me off.

Comment: I don't mind downvotes when I feel that I deserve them. I just don't think I deserve them in this case; I think my answer was perfectly reasonable. But yes, since I'm over 10k, I'm not going to delete my answer just because it has some downvotes. I just feel like they aren't particularly merited in this case.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I agree, but then I never downvoted.  In fact - just read your edit, and I'll add a +1.  Cheers.